# QT: Scrolling 2 QPlainTextEdits at the same time

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create an internal tool for my usage with 2 QPlainTextEdits. I want to make a functionality that when i scroll one text edit the other is scrolled also. I tried to figure something out from http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-codeeditor-example.html but it does not work as i expected

Here is my code:

CustomEdit.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMEDIT_H
#define CUSTOMEDIT_H

#include <QPlainTextEdit>

class CustomEdit : public QPlainTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void updatePosition(const QRect &, int);
};

#endif // CUSTOMEDIT_H
```

CustomEdit.cpp

```
#include "customedit.h"

CustomEdit::CustomEdit(QWidget *parent) : QPlainTextEdit(parent)
{

}

void CustomEdit::updatePosition(const QRect &rect, int position) {

    if (position) {
        this->scroll(0, position);
        this->update(0, rect.y(), this->width(), rect.height());
    }
    else {
        this->update(0, rect.y(), this->width(), rect.height());
    }

}
```

MainWindow constructor

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    printoutAnalyzer = new PrintoutAnalyzer();

    ui->Log->setReadOnly(true);
    ui->Progress->reset();

    resultEdit = new CustomEdit(this);
    printoutEdit = new CustomEdit(this);

    resultEdit->setReadOnly(true);
    printoutEdit->setReadOnly(true);

    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(printoutEdit);
    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(resultEdit);


    connect(printoutAnalyzer, SIGNAL(writeToLog(QString)), this, SLOT(putLogText(QString)));
    connect(printoutAnalyzer, SIGNAL(writeToResult(QString)), this, SLOT(putResultText(QString)));
    connect(printoutAnalyzer, SIGNAL(setProgress(int)), this, SLOT(setProgress(int)));
    connect(ui->LoadPrintout, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(choosePrintoutFile()));

    connect(printoutEdit, SIGNAL(updateRequest(QRect, int)), resultEdit, SLOT(updatePosition(QRect, int)));
    connect(resultEdit, SIGNAL(updateRequest(QRect, int)), printoutEdit, SLOT(updatePosition(QRect, int)));
}
```

When I execute the code and scroll one text edit the second one looks like this (text edits have the same content):

[image: Fault example]

Comment: Have you tried connecting the verticalScrollBars from both text edits using valueChanged / setValue?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple would be to keep the vertical scrollbars of your QPlainTextEdit in sync with the help of the ''sliderPosition property''.